# How can one paste to markdown in Android?

Tags: copy-paste, editing

I would like to be able to copy some text (e.g., from a website viewed in Google Chrome) and paste it so that the pasted text uses markdown, e.g. to contain links. On Microsoft Windows + Chrome, I use the Google Chrome extension  [Paste as Markdown](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paste-as-markdown/lmelpnmpkekjahgdihfajfebaddffokl?hl=th)
. How can I do that on Android?

I use Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from this Stack Overflow post, Android does not support markdown ([Markdown support in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656836/Markdown-support-in-Android-TextView))

You will need to use a third party app like [Markdown X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melody.markdown&hl=en&gl=In) (you have many others in Play Store or from lists like [Izzy's](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107))